# How do I start my VS Code Workspace with a split terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already have one split pane terminal via `tasks.json` in my `.vscode` folder for the project; this has a gulp dev task and VM launch task that run, one in each pane;

I’d like to define a second terminal with a split pane, one pane with a CWD of the workspace root and one with an arbitrary CWD.

If I do this via tasks.json they seem to be non-interactive, like they’re dedicated to that task. Is there some other way to define other terminal windows and tie that setup to this particular workspace?